# What do you call a piece of cloth used to mop the floor?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm not a native English speaker, but my wife is.  She doesn't know either.  I think I've heard people use words "rag" and "rubbish", but I'm not sure how precise and widespread this is.  If this matters, I'm interested in the word one would put on a package in a supermarket rather than use in plain everyday speech.

---

After some trial and error I found this article on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floorcloth which suggests "floorcloth".  But when I search Google for images, all I find is sorts of carpets, and nothing about cleaning.

Comment: A *cleaning cloth*? A *mop*? A *microfibre* mop? Probably not *rubbish*. Not *rug* either, unless it wasn't kept as one any longer. A *rag*, perhaps. But *rags* tend to be old clothes - it sounds odd to buy a *new* rag.

Comment: @Lawrence ouch, I meant `rag`, not `rug`. That was a mistake. I'll fix the question. Also, I thought that the mop was the entire tool (that is a handle and a bar attached to it to fix the cloth on), I didn't know one could use that to mean just the cloth.

Comment: You can mop a floor with a mop, or you can mop a floor with a bucket and an old rag. Which are you referring to? Or both?

Comment: @Clare I didn't know there was a distinction :) My two native languages are Russian and Hebrew, and none of them has separate concepts for this. However, when you translate "mop" to either language it means different tools, the action performed is the same.

Comment: Yeah, depending on the type of mop, the thing you stick at the end of the mop is a *mop cloth* or a *mop head*. Google those two terms and you might get some packaging examples. Especially if you click on "shopping" when you search. Or on  images.

Comment: When I search Google for *floor cloth*, the first result is [this absorbent cloth](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Floor-Cloths-18-inch-16-inch-U-G0175/dp/B001M13E9A). A [*mop cloth*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Enviroproducts-Ltd-DCM-E-cloth-Mop/dp/B003WKSTJY) goes on a particular type of mop. A *rag* is just a offcut or piece of (generally worn-out) material/cloth used for cleaning, but usually for really messy jobs.

Comment: @AndrewLeach this is the first link in my Google search for _floor cloth_: https://www.etsy.com/market/floorcloth . The kind of mop in the image for _mop cloth_ isn't used in households neither in Russia nor in Israel, I doubt you could even buy one from a convenience store... Though seeing how the process of cleaning is probably different in English speaking countries, perhaps _mop cloth_ would be the closest one, if that's how people actually clean the floor.

Comment: @Clare the _mop head_ one... well, I've only seen this used in McDonalds in Israel and a similar tool is used in Russian navy, but not in regular households. So, Russian navy has a special word for it. I haven't worked in McDonalds in Israel, so wouldn't know if they used the same word for the tool as they would for a regular mop... So, I'm guessing that _mop cloth_ is the one I was after.

Comment: Just for the record, this is what typical Israeli thinks of when she hears "mop": http://rslerner.co.il/758-home_default/-.jpg and this is the same, but for someone from Russia: http://www.colady.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/luchshie_shvabry_dlya_doma_-_kak_vybrat1.jpg

Comment: Always called it a 'floorcloth' myself.

Comment: My British English perspective is that while I might 'mop up' some spilled liquid with a cloth, if I'm *'mopping the floor'* I'm doing it with a dolly mop http://www.martinvitera.co.uk/images/mops4.png or a squeegee mop https://www.nzbrush.co.nz/ic/3013898770/MOP12.jpg If I'm down on my hands and knees using a cloth; I'm *'washing the floor with a cloth'*.

Comment: I found someone who worked in McDonalds in Israel. Apparently, the tool they used to clean the floor retained its English name, i.e. they would call it "mop" (מופ), while the Hebrew word for what would normally be used as a mop is "magav" (מגב). @Spagirl ok, so I believe this is due to the difference in how cleaning is performed. So, no point looking for an exact match. Anyways, this was enlightening, as I wouldn't normally ask about cleaning or see my English-speaking friends cleaning their homes :)

Comment: @wvxvw I imagine *mop top* is or at least was used also. Hence the name of the Beatles haircuts.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I mentioned you in my answer thanks again.

Comment: @Spagirl I mentioned you in my answer thanks again.

Comment: @ArmthegoodguysinAmerica I mentioned you in my answer thanks again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hardware stores in the U.S. sell packages of "new rags."  Not surprisingly, they are often named "bag-o-rags" or "box-o-rags."  Colloquially, "rag" is what the majority of native English speakers would use to describe a "cloth used to mop the floor".

I'd never use "floorcloth" and wouldn't have thought of it in 1,000 years.  When I first read the compound word in your question, "rug" was the first thing that came to mind.  A rapid search on the internet confirms this perspective.  It's the wrong rabbit to chase.

To my knowledge, there is no formal word for what you're looking for.  Colloquially, you will hear:

- Mop the floor with this rag.
- Mop the floor with that cloth.
- Mop the floor with a towel.

Therefore, I'm not surprised to find that Proctor and Gamble invented a brand name to take the place of these generally-negative words: *Swiffer.*  The name, like aspirin, kleenex, xerox, and a host of other brand names, has become so commonly used that it is losing its brand status and becoming the defacto way of describing something-with-which-you-mop-the-floor-that-you-don't-want-to-call-a-rag.

However, if you tried to use it in a commercial context, I'd expect P&G to sue you for trademark infringement.

In a commercial context...

- Mop cloth
- Mopping towel

would do, especially since the context already exists with paper towels.

Comment: "Rag is what the majority of English speakers would use to describe the cloth used to mop the floor"? Not in the UK it isn't. It's a _floorcloth_. A _rag_ here is a piece of scrap or waste fabric, usually with at least one fraying edge where the original garment or sheet has been torn (hence _ragged_). Rags _are_ used for cleaning but, when used like that, are regarded as single-use and disposable, unlike a floorcloth. Obviously an example of two nations divided by a single language!

Comment: @BoldBen you've described the American version of rag also. A torn-up piece of clothing. We use 'em for all sorts of things, such as mopping the floor.

Comment: Isn't "swiffer" used for *sweeping* the dust off floors? Does one soak a "swiffer" in water and detergent to "wash" the floor, I think not. But in Italy, we have the brand [Vileda, whereas *mocio*](http://www.vileda.com/media/wysiwyg/Shop_IT/Product/mocio16/Packshot_SM_3Action_Completo_ital_links_1__2.jpg) is the name of the broom with the strips of cloth bundled together.

Comment: Aah, "swiffer" can be used both [wet and dry](https://pgeveryday-com.secure.footprint.net/Assets/Modules/Campaigns/Product/Images/Product/00037000309420-Sweeper-Starter-Kit-Refills-Starter-Kit-590x400-3-size-3.jpg).

Comment: @Clare We use rags for all sorts of things as well. It's just that we don't call a cloth made specifically for a purpose (like a dishcloth, a duster or a floorcloth) a rag. JBH seems to do that.

Comment: Every construction job I do starts by bringing a package of toilet paper, 'sugar water', and a bag-o-rags from the store - lest we become savages and production suffers.

Comment: What you call a piece of cloth *used* to mop the floor depends whether that's what the cloth was *designed* for. If it was specifically designed for floor-mopping, it's a mop. If it's a worn-out piece of cloth designed for something else, it's a rag. If it's your best towel/jumper/skirt/trousers and in some dire emergency, you use it to mop the floor it's still a towel/jumper/skirt/trousers

Comment: I don't think this should be marked as t excepted answer, the first comment disputing it has more up votes that the answer itself...

Answer (score 0):

You are right an old pice of cloth is called rag

Comment: add a reference to your answer please

Comment: I've no idea what anyone meant and how could it not be clear that neither cloth nor rag has to do with age, please?|

Comment: It seems none uses a unique product to clean; most people use the old, unusable ones to mop. (On a lighter note, cleaning is not such a serious thing it seems.)

Answer (score 0):

Cuban Mop Cloth

I think this is the description you are looking for. When you [google Cuban Mop Cloth](https://www.google.com/search?q=Cuban%20Mop%20Cloth&hl=en&sxsrf=ALeKk00uyfc9SME8MNZnQnKagknbwRCyug:1583129585826&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZrOKkkfvnAhVN4KYKHYuzAHIQ_AUoAnoECA0QBA&biw=1422&bih=642) you see: [image]

and this is what you were looking for since this is what is used in Israel (where I come from too) I think that would be the word [סְמַרטוּט](https://translate.google.com/?source=gtx_m#view=home&op=translate&sl=iw&tl=en&text=%D7%A1%D6%B0%D7%9E%D6%B7%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%98) or in more accurate and posh Hebrew [סְחָבָה](https://translate.google.com/?source=gtx_m#view=home&op=translate&sl=iw&tl=en&text=%D7%A1%D6%B0%D7%97%D6%B8%D7%91%D6%B8%D7%94) or even [מַטלִית](https://translate.google.com/?source=gtx_m#view=home&op=translate&sl=iw&tl=en&text=%D7%A1%D6%B0%D7%97%D6%B8%D7%91%D6%B8%D7%94) which are all shown when entering [mop into google translate](https://translate.google.com/?source=gtx_m#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=iw&text=mop).

The general term is just mop which can be used as the whole tool but also just as part of it, to be more specific a mop cloth and a mop stick (I presume) are a mop but a mop cloth can also just be called a mop. Since this is confusing there are apparently many brand names which are used instead (e.g. [swiffer sweeper](https://www.google.com/search?q=swiffer%20sweeper&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwi_h_6anPvnAhXeOVAKHWfcCDUQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=swiffer%20sweeper&gs_l=img.3..0i67j0l9.10341.11471..11635...0.0..0.225.851.1j5j1......0....1..gws-wiz-img.50Za4_aY06g&ei=Zq9cXr-8Bd7zwALnuKOoAw&bih=642&biw=1422)) - like mentioned in JBH's answer.

It seems to me, there are many different ways of mopping the floor and some of them are more common in other countries than others - this is a whole topic for perhaps another question I'll try summing it up a little but it really should be done more extensively and probably on a more fitting website.

Some people use this kind of mop cloth (I have seen this a lot in Germany):
[image: ![enter image description here]

whilst others use this kind:

[image]

The first has been referred to here as a [mop cloth](https://www.google.com/search?q=mop%20cloth&rlz=1C1CHBF_enDE852DE853&sxsrf=ALeKk02X4keeNQHwa6A7_2WI-Vc-UyMbog:1583131347346&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjqnN3sl_vnAhXx0qYKHayoADAQ_AUoAnoECAwQBA&biw=1422&bih=642), [floor cloth](https://translate.google.com/?source=gtx_m#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=iw&text=floor%20cloth) (or [floorcloth](https://translate.google.com/?source=gtx_m#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=iw&text=floorcloth)) or [rag](https://translate.google.com/?source=gtx_m#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=iw&text=rag)([new rag](https://www.google.com/search?q=new%20rag%20for%20mopping&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjqotiEmPvnAhXBhrQKHdGaCQUQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=new%20rag%20for%20mopping&gs_l=img.3...249.3232..3368...0.0..0.144.1391.3j9......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......0j0i30j0i8i30j0i24.IqcAY9YvSvU&ei=BatcXqqMJMGN0gXRtaYo&bih=642&biw=1422&rlz=1C1CHBF_enDE852DE853)) depending on where you come from this might sound weird, wrong or is just not really in use.

The second has been referred to here as a [mop head](https://www.google.com/search?q=mop%20head&rlz=1C1CHBF_enDE852DE853&sxsrf=ALeKk00s2ul8L3ocv6VMus19E160nmWupw:1583131437530&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj8zt2XmPvnAhWDxMQBHTx3DDkQ_AUoAXoECA0QAw&biw=1422&bih=642) or a [dolly mop](https://www.google.com/search?q=dolly%20mop&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjTqYidmPvnAhWHAVAKHSQKAKUQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=dolly%20mop&gs_l=img.3..0l3j0i8i30j0i30j0i8i30j0i24l4.11171.14101..14296...0.0..0.209.1250.1j5j2......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i67j0i7i30j0i8i7i30.2azrMupKBlU&ei=OKtcXtOtK4eDwAKklICoCg&bih=642&biw=1422&rlz=1C1CHBF_enDE852DE853)(the handle and mop-head together).

Many thanks to all of you who commented all the comments were very useful! especially @ArmthegoodguysinAmerica, @AndrewLeach and @Spagirl

Comment: Thank you for the mention. To be honest, the ones you are calling mop cloths or floor cloths may not even *have* a single common name in British English, being a somewhat novel product. The picture shows covers that fit proprietary folding mops. Internet searches variously call those ‘mop pads’, ‘mop refills’, ‘washable mop-heads’ and ‘replacement mop covers’. A ‘dolly mop’ would be the handle and mop-head *together*.  The Cuban affair with a cloth a separate handle and bar construction is not at all familiar to me as a UK dweller.